# Using Google Picker API prevents RAMP LOAD from being issued?

Tags: google-cast, google-picker

You will need to whitelist these URLs:

```
http://cc-repro-sndr.mickens.us/
http://cc-repro-sndr2.mickens.us/
```

> (cc-repro-sndr) First press "Open Receiver", then choose "Play from Dropbox", video will play.
>
> (reload/f5)
>
> (cc-repro-sndr) First press "Open Receiver", then choose "Play from Drive", video will play.

Then, I added the Google Picker API to actually be able to choose the file from Drive.

> (reload/f5)
>
> (cc-repro-sndr **2**) First press "Open Receiver", then choose "Play from Dropbox", video will play.
>
> (reload/f5)
>
> (cc-repro-sndr **2**) First press "Open Receiver", then choose "Play from Drive", then choose an appropriate video, video does **NOT** play.

I remotely debugged the receiver app, and in the Websocket session, there is NOT a RAMP load command being sent in the last case. I can't for the life of me figure out why.

If you open the inspector, you'll see that the MediaLoadRequest objects that are created for both Drive examples are identical.

(I do apologize, the receiver URL uses a non-standard TLD and is blocked by many corporate firewalls)

Answer (score 0):

This is probably best reported as a bug on our [Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-cast-sdk/issues/entry).

Comment: If others want to follow along at home: https://code.google.com/p/google-cast-sdk/issues/detail?id=27